# Website hosted on IIS is not accessbile

Tags: iis, port

I have two sites set up in IIS on a remote machine **RM**; one on regular port 80, and the other on port 5773.

From my local machine **LM**, I can access the site on 80, but I cannot access the one on 5773; I get a status code of 502 and an error code of 10060 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) when I try to do this.

I can access the 5773 site via IIS when I am logged into RM (i.e. by right clicking on a page on the site and going 'Browse'). I can also access pages on the 5773 site via a browser, again when I am logged into RM. I just can't do the same via a browser when I am logged into LM.

I have ensured that port 5773 is open for outgoing traffic on LM.

Could the problem be that I also need to ensure that port 5773 is open for inbound traffic on RM?

Comment: Yes.  The browser request would be considered incoming traffic to the server so if you have something blocking the port the request will fail.

Comment: Q: Could the problem be that I also need to ensure that port 5773 is open for inbound traffic on RM? A: Yes. How would you expect RM to accept incoming connections on port 5773 if they're being blocked at the firewall on or in front of RM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Could the problem be that I also need to ensure that port 5773 is open for inbound traffic on RM?

Not quite.
You are connecting from LM  --> RM:5773

If there is a path from LM: --> RM:5773, all should be well (presuming normal firewall setups).

Steps:

From LM, can you telnet to RM 5773  ?

On RM can you telnet to RM 5773  ?

Something is in the way... firewalls.... etc 
The most likely causes:

- You cannot get out to inet at all on 5773 from LM
- Firewall in front of RM's IIS (network layer, or windows firewall) is blocking     inbound 5773

Comment: A netstat -ano on both servers should help narrow down where the problem is at.